# Split cell to columns depending on the value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So i have this data in column A on my spreadsheet

```
test1,test2,test3
```

It can be more than 3 values or less than 3 values and i want to split it into different columns with the comma as a delimiter. But i want to place it on a specific column depending on the value. For example if it is test1 or test2 i want it to to column B. If it is test3 or test4 i want it to go to column C.

Any ideas on how i can achieve that on google apps script?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
var str = 'test1,test2,test3,test4';
var colA = str.split(',');
var colB = [];
var colC = [];

for (var i = 0; i < colA.length; i++){
  var val = colA[i];
  if (val == 'test1' || val == 'test2'){
    colB.push(val);
  }else {
    colC.push(val)
  }
}

console.log(colB);
console.log(colC);
```

Option 2 would be to use functions like this:

```js
var str = 'test1,test2,test3,test4';
var colA = str.split(',');
var colB = [];
var colC = [];

function move_to_b(value){
  for (var i = 0; i < colA.length; i++){
    var val = colA[i];
    if (val == value){
      colB.push(val);
    }
  }
}

function move_to_c(value){
  for (var i = 0; i < colA.length; i++){
    var val = colA[i];
    if (val == value){
      colC.push(val);
    }
  }
}
move_to_b('test1');
move_to_b('test2');

move_to_c('test3');
move_to_c('test4');

console.log(colB);
console.log(colC);
```

Comment: Hey @Tim567. Thanks for the response. I think i need to look into the column as the string is not going to be the same all the time. So i need to check the column and then split.

Comment: @Andreas I don't fully understand your question.  perhaps my updated answer wil fix it?

Comment: Sorry @Tim567. Not a native speaker. I meant that the string will not always be the same  but it will always be separated by commas. So i have to get the range but when i tried to do that all i was getting was errors. I will update my original post on Monday with the script i already use and maybe u can give me your opinion. Thanks a lot